# How to force StringTemplate to evaluate attribute within attribute?

Tags: c#, stringtemplate

I have the following code:

```
StringTemplate st = new StringTemplate("$msg$");
st.SetAttribute("msg", "Hello $usr$");
st.SetAttribute("usr", "Jakub");
Console.WriteLine(st); 
// current output:  "Hello $usr$"
// expected output: "Hello Jakub"
```

Do anybody know how to force [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) to evaluate `$usr$` attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct solution should look following.

```
StringTemplate st = new StringTemplate("$msg$");
st.SetAttribute("msg", new StringTemplate("Hello $usr$"));
st.SetAttribute("usr", "Jakub");
Console.WriteLine(st); 
// current output:  "Hello Jakub"
// expected output: "Hello Jakub"
```

Next time I'll rtm twice before asking. I promise :-)